# Margin and padding (I guess) differs in browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a setup of "links" (with background) that when hovered show a box (with background) below. The box is aligned to the “links” so the backgrounds align.

This works good in latest Chrome, Opera and Safari, but in Internet Explorer and Firefox there is a difference in padding and margin (I guess).

- **[JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/kknLY/)**, obviously you need to look in different browsers :)
- **What is the cause of this and how do you fix it?**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="banner-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="banner-text"><span>Hello</span> world. <span>Hello</span> guys.
            <br/>
            <div class="banner-links">
                <table>
                    <tr class="first">
                        <td class="first">about</td>
                        <td class="second">about</td>
                        <td class="third">about</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="second">
                        <td class="first"><a href="#" onclick="return false">Lorem ipsum 1</a>

                            <div id="info-first">Perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae.</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="second"><a href="#" onclick="return false">Lorem ipsum 2</a>

                            <div id="info-second">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="third"><a href="#" onclick="return false">Lorem ipsum 3</a>

                            <div id="info-third">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: #c8c8c8;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#banner {
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom:0px solid #c83232;
    margin:4;
    display:none;
}
#banner-content-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
}
.banner-text {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 950px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family:'Berlin Sans FB';
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
}
.banner-text span {
    color: #c83232;
}
.banner-links table {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    overflow: visible;
}
.banner-links tr.first td.first {
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.banner-links tr.first td.second {
    text-align: center;
}
.banner-links tr.first td.third {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.banner-links tr.first {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family:'Verdana';
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.first {
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.second {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.third {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
}
.banner-links tr.second {
    line-height: 5px;
    overflow: visible;
}
.banner-links tr.second a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family:'Verdana';
    padding: 1px 10px 1px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: 0.5s;
    overflow: visible;
    cursor: default;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.first:hover a {
    color: #c83232;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    z-index: 1001;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.second:hover a {
    color: #c83232;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    z-index: 1001;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.third:hover a {
    color: #c83232;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    z-index: 1001;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.first:hover #info-first {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.first #info-first {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -365px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    overflow: visible;
    font-family:'Verdana';
    line-height: 17px;
    color: #323232;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.second:hover #info-second {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.second #info-second {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -365px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    overflow: visible;
    font-family:'Verdana';
    line-height: 17px;
    color: #323232;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.third:hover #info-third {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.third #info-third {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -365px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    overflow: visible;
    font-family:'Verdana';
    line-height: 17px;
    color: #323232;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Cause: Browser’s default stylesheets. Fix: If you don’t like those default margin/padding values, then explicitly provide your own.

Comment: Don't use tables for **anything** other than tabular data. If you want to build a table-like layout use the appropriate display properties.

Comment: @Nit Okey, interesting. I just started do websites and coding a few weeks ago. But display property you say? So like for those three ‘links’ I should use like ‘display: inline’ and then center a wrapping div of those ‘links’?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, but roughly yes.

Answer (score 0):

You're using tables which is terrible practice today. I highly suggest doing additional research on modern front end development techniques and markup. Even go grab a copy of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) and look into a number of components they offer out of the box.

Attempting to browser debug the code you've supplied wouldn't be good - A lot of unnecessary work on a code base that's incorrect to begin with.

Comment: Alright. So how do you accomplish it by using correct code? Is it by using UL and LI and display properties like block and inline? I’m very new to all this. Started just a few weeks back.

Comment: to write a better codebase for the supplied example above is a large task and not something I could accomplish in a SO comment. For the sake of your example you could utilize the bootstrap library, create a three column grid for the hoverable titles, then add the content below (outside of the 3 columns) - You can add event listeners to the hover of the titles and show/hide relevant content. A pure css approach like you have is good but browser compat and scalability will be hindered. In short - using good markup and css styles including float:left and width:33% you should be able to get it